# Validating MS Teams channel names, team name and channel address in one go //OwMyHead

Tags: regex

Validating MS Teams channel names, team name and channel address in one go! However having problems checking that Teams channel name or Teams team name doesnt include a channel address...

I have this which works:

Regex1:

```
^(?![\s._])([^~#%&*{}+:<>?|\n]{1,50})(?<![.])( - ).{1,256}$
```

Which would validate this successfully:
MonkeyChannel - MonkeyTeam

but I need to check also that it doesn't contain the channel address like so:
MonkeyChannel - MonkeyTeam 12337aab.domain.com@emea.teams.ms

so basically I'm thinking I need to incorporate this which looks for a channel address:

Regex2:

```
(?<![[a-z0-9]{8}\.domain\.com@emea\.teams\.ms])
```

into this somehow:

Regex1:

```
^(?![\s._])([^~#%&*{}+:<>?|\n]{1,50})(?<![.])( - ).{1,256}$
```

My guess looks something like this but its not working:

Regex3:

```
^(?![\s._])([^~#%&*{}+:<>?|\n]{1,50})(?<![.])( - ).{1,256}(?<![[a-z0-9]{8}\.domain\.com@emea\.teams\.ms])$
```

Any wizards who can spot the error of my ways?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ has a cute little debugger

Comment: Just remove the last `]` and use a single `[` at the beginning of the  lookbehind.